# How to start rocket chat?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, rocket.chat

How do I run rocketchat locally? I am stuck here for 2 days. I made a clone of the github repository at [Rocket Chat](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat) and tried the manual steps here at [installation steps](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/). But how do I start the server? I have installed mongodb.

Comment: As the tag says: `For questions about general use, not development or programming, use https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues. `

Comment: @fvu I don't think, there is an issue. I am not getting the starting point:)

Comment: You're neither programming nor developing rocketchat, so SO is **not** the right place for your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after cloning the repository, you need to install the dependencies of Rocket Chat with the command:

```
npm install
```

This command should be run from programs/server folder. After that export these bash variables as mentioned in the install guide:

```
export ROOT_URL=http://your-host-name.com-as-accessed-from-internet:3000/
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/rocketchat
export PORT=3000
```

Then go to the main Rocket Chat directory and run the command: node main.js

After that your Rocket Chat should be running on port 3000

Comment: Thanks.   after added         export PORT=3000   rocket chat is running.